# Heatmap in R "How I can reduce the size of the letters?"

Tags: r, heatmap

I've made my first heat map in R, but I need to reduce the size of the letters of my graph, because it looks very messy.

[image]

I don't know how to reduce the size of the letters of Y (axial). The final code I used to make the heat map:

```
characlist <- list(list(c(1, 2, 3, 4)), c(1, 3, 2, NA))
str(characlist)
heatmap(as.matrix(Mydata),
        scale = "column",
        col = heat.colors(2),
        main = "Title",
        Rowv = NA,
        Colv = NA)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `cexRow` and `cexCol` as arguments to `heatmap()`